# JQUERY UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to open a jquery UI dialog once, automatically. This can be done by setting the autoOpen property to true. But i need that to happen only once. How should I do it.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I don't follow...it only opens when you *create* it...are you trying to create an already existing dialog?

Comment: ah, see that's a completely different question, the page refreshing is a *huge* difference in JavaScript.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Is there any way to dynamically set its autoOpen property to false dynamically...

Comment: @sje397: my dialog definition already has what u hav given

Answer (score 1):

Since this is across pageloads, I'd set a cookie (via [the cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) in this example), like this:

```
var seenBefore = $.cookie("dialogOnce") == "1";
$("#elem").dialog({
  autoOpen: !seenBefore,
  open: function() { 
    //we've seen it, don't show for 180 days
    $.cookie("dialogOnce", "1", { expires: 180 }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: So do i need to download that plugin?

Comment: @Kut - yup, it's pretty small: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js